# Create curved card with shadow

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I really need you because I don't have even start idea how to implement these, and also I am not sure how it is called.

Actually, I want to implement something similar like on image (this little circle in each of cards - that is like chain between two cards).

[image]

With help of [key](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4571911/key) I have made image from up with this code:

```js
class InfoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  InfoPage();

  @override
  _InfoPageState createState() => _InfoPageState();
}

class _InfoPageState extends State<InfoPage> {
  InfoItemModel infoData = dataSourceInfoUser;
  double basicSize = 70;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Example'),
    ),
    body: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 150,
                  child: AppCardField(
                    child: Text('Something'),
                  ),
                ),
                _buildCardWithCircle(
                  bgCircleX: 0.78,
                  bgCirceY:  -2.0,
                  innerContainerX: 0.756,
                  innerContainerY: -1.78,
                  colorInner: Colors.orange
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
  );

  _buildCardWithCircle({double bgCircleX, double bgCirceY, double innerContainerX, double innerContainerY, Color colorInner}) => Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 150,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 150,
              child: AppCardField(
                child: Text('Something'),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment(bgCircleX, bgCirceY),
              child: Container(
                height: basicSize,
                width: basicSize,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment(innerContainerX, innerContainerY),
              child: Container(
                height: basicSize - 10,
                width: basicSize - 10,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: colorInner,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                ),
                child: Icon(Icons.vertical_align_center),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
}

class AppCardField extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final double height;
  final double paddingVertical, paddingHorizontal;
  final double paddingVerticalChild, paddingHorizontalChild;

  AppCardField({
    this.child,
    this.height,
    this.paddingVertical = 8,
    this.paddingHorizontal = 16,
    this.paddingVerticalChild = 8,
    this.paddingHorizontalChild = 16,
    Key key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: paddingVertical, horizontal: paddingHorizontal),
      child: Container(
        height: height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.red,
              blurRadius: 15.0,
              offset: Offset(0.0, 5.0),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: paddingVerticalChild,
              horizontal: paddingHorizontalChild),
          child: child,
        ),
      ));
}
```

But here, I have problem with shadow of the card and strongly white background of circle, OFC I need this shadow to be also in this white space, question is how to solve this?

Comment: You've got to post an attempt! Why don't you start by creating the card without the chain between them. You can use a Card or a Container. Either one can have a shadow effect. Based on this image you posted, I'd go with a container. Whichever widget you choose will have to go in a ListView or a Column.

Comment: What I would do it, of course after creating a cart, add a Stack, and a container with the same background color, and and a border radius of cicle so it taks a circular form, make another one and put it above that one. for the chain rectangle use a container without padding.  if you want to do it custom then the video you showed is not what you are looking for, it's more this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kp14Y4uHpHs

Comment: @EricDuffett Hi, you are right but until this point I didn't have attempt, didn't have idea. But key has helped me so I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Some Stuff"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 150.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        blurRadius: 20.0
                    )
                  ]
              ),
              child: Card(
                elevation: 20.0,
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                child: Text('Something'),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 150.0,
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 150.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              blurRadius: 20.0
                          )
                        ]
                    ),
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.blueGrey,
                      child: Text('Something'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment(0.9,-1.5),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 50.0,
                      width: 50.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment(0.88,-1.35),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 40.0,
                      width: 40.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.orange,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment(0.85, -1.2),
                      child: Icon(Icons.access_alarms, color: Colors.white,)
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

then you just reaped the card for the other once with different alignment values.

Comment: Hello @key, you have helped me a lot and I have updated my question. Maybe in first post I was not clear. The issue is that I don't have the chain between two cards, just circle which will connect them. But, based on your code I have implement the updated question. Now, only remains this shadow of red color around of card, do you have any idea?

Comment: Hello @key, I still have clear white circle with your code. [Image](http://prntscr.com/oly4hd) I need that this circle has inner shadow same as shadows on card. So that it is not so sharp.

Comment: Hi, thank you a lot for your effort. Your updated code is the same as my in updated question. Can you please look for this [image](https://prnt.sc/on2b0c).

Comment: Or you can look for this [image](http://prntscr.com/on2dez). So the black border around the card needs to be like that in app.